# My C program outputs itself

Tags: c

Why is my program reading the program itself instead of my text file? What I'm trying to do is read a text file and find out which line of text is the longest, then output that line and how many characters it contains.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line size */

int getline1(char line[], int maxline);
void copy1(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */
int main(void)
{
  int len;               /* current line length */
  int max;               /* maximum length seen so far */
  char line[MAXLINE];    /* current input line */
  char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

  max = 0;

  FILE *ptr_file;       
  ptr_file =fopen("textfile.txt","r");
  if (!ptr_file)
  return 1;

  while (fgets(line,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
  //printf("%s",line);
  //fclose(ptr_file);
  //return 0;

  while((len = getline1(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
  {
    printf("%d: %s", len, line);

    if(len > max)
    {
      max = len;
      copy1(longest, line);
    }
  }
  if(max > 0)
  {
    printf("Longest is %d characters:\n%s", max, longest);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;

} //end main

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline1(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i, j;

  for(i = 0, j = 0; (c = getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
  {
    if(i < lim - 1)
    {
      s[j++] = c;
    }
  }
  if(c == '\n')
  {
    if(i <= lim - 1)
    {
      s[j++] = c;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  s[j] = '\0';
  return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume 'to' is big enough */
void copy1(char to[], char from[])
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
  {
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it output actually, what do you had expected it should print and what's in textfile.txt?

Comment: Is that use of `getchar()` correct? It looks like you read a string of up to 1000 from the file, then overwrite it from `stdin`?

Comment: You know, there's a function called `strcpy` declared in `<string.h>` that already does `copy1`'s job.

Comment: You are using getchar() inside a loop of fgets(). Not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop in you main should look like (don't need the inner loop in which inside `getline1()` `getchar()` reads from stdin):

```
  while (fgets(line, 1000, ptr_file)!=NULL) {
    len = strlen(line);
    if (len > max) {
      max = len;
      strncpy(longest, line, 1000);
  }
```